Set assemblies version to all .NET Framework projects
I would like to set version and other information (Company, copyright, ..) to all my assemblies.
I'm using a directory.build.props file where all these information are stored as properties :
<Project>
   <PropertyGroup>
      <AssemblyVersion>3.1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
      <AssemblyFileVersion>3.1.0.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
      <FileVersion>3.1.0.0</FileVersion>
      <GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
      <Company>My company</Company>
      <Copyright>(C) 2024</Copyright>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

It's working fine with sdk-style projects, but it's not working with legacy .NET Framework projects.
I'm looking (if possible..) for a common and simple way to manage both sdk-style and NET framework projects. If a common way is (probably) not possible, what is the easiest way to manage this in legacy projects?
Some years ago, there was a msbuild extension pack that did the job, which has not been updated for years...

SDK-style projects can target .NET Framework; so unless you're using legacy asp.net (which gets trickier): just update the legacy .NET Framework projects to SDK-style projects with (for example) <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>

@MarcGravell Unfortunately I have some legacy asp.net projects...

The assembly info properties are a feature of SDK style projects and are not supported by legacy style projects. More than a year ago I submitted a feature request that you might consider supporting. See Feature Request: Back port GenerateAssemblyInfo from Sdk projects to Legacy projects
